# Looking for Experienced & Knowledgeable CIVICRM Freelancer

Tags: joomla, php, mysql, developer, issues

Looking for referrals for a knowledgeable, experienced CIVICRM expert (not a consulting company) that freelances and that I could keep on retainer to assist with CIVICRM technical and application issues as they arise.  We use Joomla 4 as our CMS and are on CIVICRM 5.67.1.

Comment: Despite being 'consultlng companies' some of these will do that: https://civicrm.org/civicrm/experts

Comment: I might be able to help - feel free to reach out so we can chat.

Comment: You might have a look at https://support.creative-graphics.ch/ and contact me if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to avoid large consulting companies, note that there are very few of those in the Civi ecosystem. Most of the people listed at https://civicrm.org/civicrm/experts are individuals or small teams, and they are all very knowledgable. Since you are using Joomla, you might want to narrow your search to those who have experience with that platform.